# Discord.js API invisible identifier

Tags: javascript, discord.js

[image]

As in the image above, you see that once i run my discord.js bot for some magical reason it thinks there's an identifier that is completely invisible?

here's the line:

```
var Demanding Boss = "**Demanding Boss:** Your pushing of minions with healthy competition has caused unhealthy competition"
```

Comment: You can not use space between variable names. Try `Demanding_Boss` or `DemandingBoss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have variables with spaces on the name.
So your variable would need to be `var Demanding_Boss = "";`

Comment: OHH i feel completely blind, yeah i have about 200 variables its hard to notice. Thank you! hopefully this will solve anyone else that encounters this issue